# backgroundImage path for css from public folder not working after build in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have added image path from **public folder** in App.css

It's working in local but not working after generating a build.

You may access my code on codesandbox at below path:

https://codesandbox.io/s/reactimagepath-sjtri

Please check and guide me towards solution.

Comment: change the background image path to an absolute path instead of a relative path like this: ```background-image: url("./images/texture.jpg");```

Comment: try absolute path too like '/assets/images/texture.jpg'

Comment: this solution working in codesandbox, but not working when we do NPM START in local. i have download this codesandbox and tried.

Comment: showing below error:



Failed to compile.

./src/styles.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-3-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/styles.css)
Module not found: Can't resolve './images/texture.jpg' in '/Users/hemant/Rahul/reactimagepath/src'

Answer (score 1):

Move your images folder inside src folder

**src/images/texture.jpg**

and replace your `background-image: url("./images/texture.jpg");`

or `background-image: url("../images/texture.jpg");`

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url("./images/texture.jpg");  // or url("../images/texture.jpg");
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Reference- when to use public folder [reactjs recommendation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/)

Comment: I want my all images in root after generating build so i have added in public. is there any other solution to target image from public folder?

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your css like this:

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url("./images/texture.jpg");
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: showing below error:



Failed to compile.

./src/styles.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-3-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/styles.css)
Module not found: Can't resolve './images/texture.jpg' in '/Users/hemant/Rahul/reactimagepath/src'

Comment: @RahulShah you may keep the images inside an asset/images folder under `src`. It won't create any issue.

Comment: yes, I can add in assets, but for this case i have to put images in public for direct access from FTP.

Comment: I've not encountered this case but one of my colleague suggests reinstalling of webpack as it worked for him. 
`npm install --save-dev webpack`.  
Please see if that works in your case. And, if not, I'd suggest you to share the screenshot of the complete error.